# How to get Component Props Dynamically in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I'm using Nuxt.js to build my application.

I'm creating an app that will showcase all our components for documentation purposes.
I have the following:

`<show-component name="my-component"></show-component>`

And my Nuxt.js `global.js` file imports and sets my components:

```
import ShowComponent from '../components/ShowComponent.vue'
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent.vue'

Vue.component('show-component', ShowComponent)
Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent)
```

What I would like to do at this point is show on the screen the `props` that are being used by the component, in this case: `my-component`

I'm already able to use `<my-component>` in my template code. How would I go about using it in my JS code? Something like:

`let component = getInstanceOf('my-component');
console.log(component.props);`

It would be nice to get the full representation of `props` that I defined on `my-component`

Answer (score 1):

To print an array of props:
`console.log(Object.keys(component.props))`

Comment: But `component` is not an available variable. I'm trying to figure out how to actually get information about a component into a variable.

Comment: @Justin Maybe I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. If you're outside the context of a component you can import the component as you did above and access the available props by `Object.keys(MyComponent.props)`. If you are within the context of a component you can call Object.keys(this.$options.props), to get an array of that component's available props.

Answer (score 0):

One way to access a component by name from the main Vue instance is this:

```
let componentName = 'my-component';
const component = this.$options.components[componentName];
```

If you need to access this from inside another component, you would first have to reference the main Vue instance, which would be `this.$root`, i.e.

```
const component = this.$root.$options.components[componentName];
```

and to access the props of that component:

```
let props = component.options.props;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: First question I have, is there ever a way to make use of the `this` instance if in the code block before `export default`? Or, perhaps there was some method I can use to initialize some variable which can then by accessible from all the other methods I define in that area.

Comment: Main vue instance `const vm = new Vue(...)` and then  `vm.$options.components[componentName]`? Why do you need that in the case you describe?